# How to set certificate purposes?

Tags: c#, x509certificate2

There is a GlobalSign CA. In most cases its root certificate is already exists in the Windows Certificates storage.
But sometimes (especially on old Windows versions) the storage doesn't contain the certificate.

I need to check if the certificate exists and import it if does not. I exported the certificate to a file and imported it using the code below:

```
public void ImportCertificate(StoreName storeName,
    StoreLocation location,
    byte[] certificateData)
{
    X509Store x509Store = new X509Store(storeName, location);
    X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(certificateData);
    x509Store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
    x509Store.Add(certificate);
    x509Store.Close();
}
```

The code adds the certificate but all certificate purposes are checked:

[image: Result]

I don't want to add extra purposes to the certificate just want to set those ones which have other root CAs like below:

[image: Expect]

How to do it programatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [`CertSetCertificateContextProperty`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-certsetcertificatecontextproperty) function to set store-attached properties.

In the `dwPropId` parameter you pass `CERT_ENHKEY_USAGE_PROP_ID`. You can find its numeric value in Wincrypt.h C++ header file. In a given case, `dwPropId` is 9:

```
#define CERT_ENHKEY_USAGE_PROP_ID           9
```

In the `dwFlags` you pass zero (0).

In the `pvData` parameter (which is `IntPtr` in managed signature) you pass an unmanaged pointer to an ASN.1-encoded byte array that represents a collection of object identifiers where each OID represents explicitly enabled key usage.

Here is the interop signature:

```
[DllImport("Crypt32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern Boolean CertSetCertificateContextProperty(
    [In] IntPtr pCertContext,
    [In] UInt32 dwPropId,
    [In] UInt32 dwFlags,
    [In] IntPtr pvData,
);
```

Add usings reference to `System.Runtime.InteropServices` namespace.

Next, prepare a collection of key usages:

1. create a new instance of `OidCollection` class.
2. add required OIDs to the collection.
3. Use created OID collection to instantiate the `X509EnhancedKeyUsageExtension` class. This ctor overload is fine: `X509EnhancedKeyUsageExtension(OidCollection, Boolean)`.
4. `RawData` property of EKU extension will contain ASN.1-encoded byte array which will be passed to `CertSetCertificateContextProperty` function.

Last parameter of `CertSetCertificateContextProperty` function is of `IntPtr` type and expects a pointer to an unmanaged memory block, so:

1. Use `Marshal.AllocHGlobal(eku.RawData.Length)` to allocate the properly sized buffer in unmanaged memory.
2. Use `Marshal.Copy(byte[], IntPtr, int, int)` static method overload to copy `eku.RawData` byte array to unmanaged pointer acquired in step 1.
3. call the `CertSetCertificateContextProperty` function. If it returns `true` then everything is ok.

After finishing all job, you must release unmanaged resources to avoid memory leak. Use `Marshal.FreeHGlobal(IntPtr)` method to release the pointer acquired during `Marshal.AllocHGlobal` call.

Comment: Crypt32, Many thanks for the detailed answer. It is more complex then I thought.

Comment: I've submitted my own answer that corrects some problems with this one, if you update yours I'll delete mine.

Answer (score 0):

I lack the reputation to comment on other answers but Crypt32's answer is actually incorrect in two places so I'm posting a new answer that is based on Crypt32's answers.

1. `pvData` of [`CertSetCertificateContextProperty`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-certsetcertificatecontextproperty) cannot accept `X509EnhancedKeyUsageExtension.RawData` directly, it needs to be in a [`CRYPT_INTEGER_BLOB`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/aa381414(v=vs.85)) struct
2. The function signature of `Marshal.Copy` is incorrect, it should be [`Marshal.Copy(Byte[], Int32, IntPtr, Int32)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.copy?view=netframework-4.8#system-runtime-interopservices-marshal-copy(system-byte()-system-int32-system-intptr-system-int32))

With this in mind, let's start from the top:

0. Make sure you obtain the [`X509Certificate2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2?view=netframework-4.8) you require (`Certificate`), probably from a [`X509Store`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509store.open?view=netframework-4.8) that has been opened as [`ReadWrite`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.openflags?view=netframework-4.8).
1. Import the Interop Signature and use the `System.Runtime.InteropServices` namespace.

```
[DllImport("Crypt32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern Boolean CertSetCertificateContextProperty(
    [In] IntPtr pCertContext,
    [In] UInt32 dwPropId,
    [In] UInt32 dwFlags,
    [In] IntPtr pvData,
);
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet=CharSet.Unicode)]
public struct CRYPTOAPI_BLOB {
    public uint cbData;
    public IntPtr pbData;
}
```

2. Create an [`OidCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.oidcollection?view=netframework-4.8) instance
3. Add the require OIDs of the EKUs you desire to the OidCollection
4. Create an [`X509EnhancedKeyUsageExtension`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509enhancedkeyusageextension.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#system-security-cryptography-x509certificates-x509enhancedkeyusageextension-ctor(system-security-cryptography-oidcollection-system-boolean)) instance (`eku`) using the OidCollection
5. Use `Marshal.AllocHGlobal(eku.RawData.Length)` to allocate the properly sized buffer in unmanaged memory as `pbData`
6. Use `Marshal.AllocHGlobal` with the size of the `CRYPT_INTEGER_BLOB` struct to allocate the properly sized buffer in unmanaged memory as `pvData`
7. Create an instance of the `CRYPT_INTEGER_BLOB` struct and allocate `pbData` to it and the length, `eku.RawData.Length`, to `cbData`
8. Use [`Marshal.StructureToPtr`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.structuretoptr?view=netframework-4.8#system-runtime-interopservices-marshal-structuretoptr(system-object-system-intptr-system-boolean)) to assign the `CRYPT_INTEGER_BLOB` struct to `pvData`
9. Call [`CertSetCertificateContextProperty`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-certsetcertificatecontextproperty) with `pCertContext` as `Certificate.Handle`, `dwPropId` being `CERT_ENHKEY_USAGE_PROP_ID` which is `9`, `dwFlags` of `0` and `pvData` as `pvData`. It will return return `true` if successful, it may throw an error regarding a memory access exception if the Certificate Handle you passed into it is read-only, make sure it's from an `X509Store` opened as `ReadWrite`.
10. Free allocated unmanaged memory via `Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pvData)` and `Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pbData)`
11. Close any Opened `X509Store`

Again, thanks to Crypt32 for this answer.