# Setting a CA Certificate, with specific Enabled Purposes, using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, pki, certificate-authority, certificate-store

How do I programmatically change the Enabled Purposes of a Certificate Authority, in the relevant Windows Certificate Store, using PowerShell?

This is possible to do in the [Certificates MMC snap-in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAXRR.png)

Is this only possible using P/Invoke with [`CertSetCertificateContextProperty`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-certsetcertificatecontextproperty) as per [StackOverflow: How to set certificate purposes? {C#}](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53869002)

Ideally, I want to import a custom Trusted Root Certificate Authority and only enable it for the purpose of Client Authentication.

Comment: Normally a Trusted Root CA on a computer is for a Server Authentication purpose. A server which present a certificate that has been delivered by this CA will be trusted because your local computer trust the CA. 
It is only if you own a certificate delivered by the CA and that you want to present this certificate to a server that in such case you would trust on the server side the CA for the purpose of Client Authentication.
I've not found better answer than the one you found to enable a specific key usage. This can be translated to Powershell.

Comment: In my use-case, I need to import a Certificate into a Personal store for use in Client Authentication. You cannot do this unless the signing Certificate is trusted for that purpose but I do not want to trust this Certificate for any other purpose by Client Authentication (eg: Server Authentication) as it exposes the client to unnecessary risk and the signing Certificate key holder to unnecessary liability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A PowerShell Cmdlet that uses [`CertSetCertificateContextProperty`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-certsetcertificatecontextproperty) at it's core. Thank you to [Crypt32](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3997611) and their answer on another post for guidance.

Example Usage:

```
Set-CertificateEku -StoreLocation 'CurrentUser' -StoreName 'Root' -CertificateThumbprint 'ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff' -Oids @("1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2") # Client Authentication
```

```
Function Set-CertificateEku {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [ValidateSet('CurrentUser', 'LocalMachine')]
        $StoreLocation,
        
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        $StoreName,

        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        $CertificateThumbprint,

        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        $Oids
    )
    $StoreLocation = switch($StoreLocation) {
        'CurrentUser' {
            [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.StoreLocation]::CurrentUser
        }
        'LocalMachine' {
            [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.StoreLocation]::LocalMachine
        }
    }
    try {
        $CertificateStore = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store]::new($StoreName, $StoreLocation)
        $CertificateStore.Open([System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.OpenFlags]::ReadWrite -bor [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.OpenFlags]::OpenExistingOnly)
    } catch {
        Write-Error "Could not Open Certificate Store $StoreName in $StoreLocation"
        return $false
    }
    $Certificates = $CertificateStore.Certificates.Find(
        [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509FindType]::FindByThumbprint,
        $CertificateThumbprint,
        $false
    )
    if($Certificates.Count -eq 0) {
        Write-Error "Could not find Certificate $CertificateThumbprint in $StoreName in $StoreLocation"
        return $false
    }
    $Certificate = $Certificates[0]
    

    $PKICrypt32 = @"
    [DllImport("Crypt32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern bool CertSetCertificateContextProperty(
        IntPtr pCertContext,
        uint dwPropId,
        uint dwFlags,
        IntPtr pvData
    );
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet=CharSet.Unicode)]
    public struct CRYPTOAPI_BLOB {
        public uint cbData;
        public IntPtr pbData;
    }
"@
    Add-Type -MemberDefinition $PKICrypt32 -Namespace 'PKI' -Name 'Crypt32'

    $OIDs = [Security.Cryptography.OidCollection]::new()
    foreach($Oid in $Oids) {
        [void]$OIDs.Add([Security.Cryptography.Oid]::new($Oid))
    }
    $EKU = [Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509EnhancedKeyUsageExtension]::new($OIDs, $false)
    $pbData = [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::AllocHGlobal($EKU.RawData.Length)
    [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::Copy($EKU.RawData, 0, $pbData, $EKU.RawData.Length)

    $Blob = New-Object PKI.Crypt32+CRYPTOAPI_BLOB -Property @{
        cbData = $EKU.RawData.Length;
        pbData = $pbData;
    }
    $pvData = [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::AllocHGlobal([Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SizeOf([type][PKI.Crypt32+CRYPTOAPI_BLOB]))
    [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::StructureToPtr($Blob, $pvData, $false)

    $Result = [PKI.Crypt32]::CertSetCertificateContextProperty($Certificate.Handle, 9, 0, $pvData)
    [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::FreeHGlobal($pvData)
    [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::FreeHGlobal($pbData)
    $CertificateStore.Close()
    return $Result
}
```