# CertSetCertificateContextProperty returning true but no changes in the certificate

Tags: com-interop, x509certificate2

so I have an issue now with Windows Certificates. I have a list of certificates (identified by SerialNumber/Thumbprint) for which I have to set **EnhancedKeyUsage**

So what I would like to happen is for a certificate:

[image]

From code to "Enable only for following purposes" and only "Client Authentication" to be selected, basically I would like to set a specific certificate as client auth certificate.

So the end-result should be :

[image]

Now from what I've read only ( information is very limited) I found that I should use **CertSetCertificateContextProperty** from Crypt32.dll.

My code looks like this:

```
      public async Task<bool> SetAuthKeyUsageExtension(string certThumbprint)
            {
               //open certificate store for Read/Write
                using X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
                store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
             
//find certificate
                var certificate = FindCertificate(certThumbprint, store);
        
                if (certificate != null)
                {
//set EKU for Client Auth
                    SetKeyExtangeUsage(certificate);
    
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }


  private X509Certificate2 FindCertificate(string thumbPrint, X509Store store)
        {
            X509Certificate2Collection foundX509Certificates = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, thumbPrint, false);

           
            if (foundX509Certificates != null || foundX509Certificates.Count > 0)
            {
                return foundX509Certificates.FirstOrDefault();
            }

            return null;
        }
```

My native class looks like this:

```
  [DllImport("Crypt32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        internal static extern Boolean CertSetCertificateContextProperty(
            [In] IntPtr pCertContext,
            [In] UInt32 dwPropId,
            [In] UInt32 dwFlags,
            [In] IntPtr pvData);



        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public struct CRYPT_OBJID_BLOB
        {
            public uint cbData;
            public IntPtr pbData;
        }
        private const string OID_PKIX_KP_CLIENT_AUTH = "1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2";
        private const int CERT_ENHKEY_USAGE_PROP_ID = 9;


    public static bool SetKeyExtangeUsage(X509Certificate2 cert)
            {
//Create a new Oid collection
                OidCollection oids = new OidCollection();
    //add to collection 
                oids.Add(new Oid
                {
                    Value = OID_PKIX_KP_CLIENT_AUTH
                });
    
                X509EnhancedKeyUsageExtension eku = new X509EnhancedKeyUsageExtension(oids, true);
    
                //pbData
                var pbData = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(eku.RawData.Length);
    
                CRYPT_OBJID_BLOB objID = new CRYPT_OBJID_BLOB();
    
                IntPtr pvData = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(objID));
    
                objID.pbData = pbData;
                objID.cbData = (uint)eku.RawData.Length;
    
                Marshal.StructureToPtr(objID, pvData, false);
    
           // var result = CertSetCertificateContextProperty(cert.Handle, CERT_ENHKEY_USAGE_PROP_ID, 0, objID.pbData);

        var result = CertSetCertificateContextProperty(cert.Handle, CERT_ENHKEY_USAGE_PROP_ID, 0, pvData);
    
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(objID.pbData);
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pvData);
    
                return true;
            }
```

[image]

This code "works" in terms that it does not break or throw any errors, but when I check the certificate using the UI, no Extended Key Usage are changed, basically it looks like I did nothing. I am sure I am missing something, but I have very few experience with **X509Certificate2**  and also **Interop** so I am guessing that somewhere in **SetKeyExtangeUsage** I am missing something. 5

I used this [How to set certificate purposes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53867961/how-to-set-certificate-purposes) as reference, but there is no working code there, only steps, which I think I followed.

Any ideas, what I am missing?

NEDIT: Now running the same code I get this error:
**"Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt."**

EDIT2: Changed pbData to pvData as mentioned.

EDIT3: Changed function

```
public static bool SetClientAuthEKU(X509Certificate2 cert)
        {
            OidCollection oids = new OidCollection();

            oids.Add(new Oid
            {
                Value = OID_PKIX_KP_CLIENT_AUTH
            });

            X509EnhancedKeyUsageExtension eku = new X509EnhancedKeyUsageExtension(oids, true);

            CRYPT_OBJID_BLOB objID = new CRYPT_OBJID_BLOB();

            //allocate space in memory
            IntPtr pbData = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(eku.RawData.Length);
            IntPtr pvData = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(objID));

            //copy eku raw data into pbData
            Marshal.Copy(eku.RawData, 0, pbData, eku.RawData.Length);

            //set CRYPT_OBJECT value with ekuRaw data and Length
            objID.pbData = pbData;
            objID.cbData = (uint)eku.RawData.Length;

            //copy CRYPT OBJECT into IntPtr
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(objID, pvData, false);

            var result = CertSetCertificateContextProperty(cert.Handle, CERT_ENHKEY_USAGE_PROP_ID, 0, pvData);


            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(objID.pbData);
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pvData);

            return true;
        }
```

EDIT4:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you pass actual raw data (without length indicator) to `CertSetCertificateContextProperty` function, while it must be a pointer to `CRYPTOAPI_BLOB`. That is, last parameter of `CertSetCertificateContextProperty` function must be `pvData`.

The mistake can be easily detected by finding usages of `pvData` in your code. You write structure into `pvData` pointer, but the pointer is not used anywhere in the code.

**Update:**

I just noticed that you don't put anything in `pbData`. You allocate the buffer, but don't write anything there. You have to copy extension's raw data into `pbData` buffer.

Comment: @Crypto32 I've changed it, please take a look at the edit. I still have the same result, nothing is changed inside the certificate.

Comment: see update section in my response.

Comment: @Crypto32, check my last edit, I hope everything is in order, but this still produces no changes, despite the function returns true.

Comment: Does the function call succeed? If not, what is the error code?

Comment: @Crypto32 it returns true, but not sure if there is an error ( I assumed no) I will check the code tomorrow and will let you know.

Comment: @Cyrto32 no errors, returns true. Check my last update.

Comment: Did you re-open certificate manager? Keep in mind that certificate manager aggressively cache data and it may be possible that you are looking at cached data.

Comment: @Crypto32, indeed this was the problem. re-open certificate manager made it work. So I was checking a cached version, took me half a day to figure it out. You learn something everyday, thank you for the help!